# Emacs 21 C/C++ auto-complete mode

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, elisp

I am working on a server which uses a really old emacs. The only way to install plugins is by downloading the .el files and adding them to the `~/.emacs/` folder and then sourcing it from the main `.emacs` file. Would someone know of a C/C++ autocomplete plugin which works with Emacs 21? I tried `auto-complete-mode` but I get an error.

```
An error has occurred while loading `/home/sbhalla/.emacs':

Symbol's function definition is void: defvaralias
```

The same `auto-complete-mode` works fine on emacs 22.

Comment: You may get by by just commenting out `defvarialias`'s. You might need to comment out some other stuff too, but you might be surprised that the library generally works OK. I have no idea whether that will be true, but it's worth a quick try.

Comment: Hi @Drew I am sorry but that doesn't work

Comment: It's not ideal but you could turn the aliases into variables and ensure that you set both vars to the same value.  Indicate in the doc for the var in case you forget.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to run Emacs 24 without root access:

1. Download and untar Emacs 24: http://gnu.mirror.iweb.com/emacs/emacs-24.5.tar.gz
2. `./configure && make`. It may tell you to disable some options, e.g. I had to compile `./configure --without-jpg --without-png`
3. You should be able to run `./src/emacs`

I've done this to get the latest version of Emacs on university machines without sudo access, so it could probably work for you too.

Comment: Hi Brian. I was going to do the same. But I actually want to find a solution to the small problem, rather than re-install the whole thing for just auto-complete